# webservice request sniffer

Tags: java, web-services

I create webservice proxy and I am sending some data do async web service. How can I see what I am sending to web service (wthat xml exactly I send). I am using jdeveloper. Does anyone know any good sniffer for this or how can I see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

If you need something for Linux take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2) but if you are from Java community you will definitely should try [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project)

Comment: thx all for answe. I already look wireshark but it is to complicated. Is anything simplier?

Comment: Fiddler is rather simple. And it was design specifically for developers to do such stuff. You don't need to even install it. There are even addins for some browsers.

Comment: Thank you! You save my life!

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a linux box, you cann use [justniffer](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Fiddler, you can always use a common sniffer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if your application does not use https. In particular wireshark will work on non-windows environments.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting one more tool for posterity - [NetTool](http://nettool.sourceforge.net/) . This has served me beautifully in the past

Answer (score 1):

I have been using apache's tcpmon (https://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/). Its a rather simplistic connection-forwarder (tcp connections only, gui, written in java) but it does what it says on the tin.